# Googlemaps works local but not live

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, local, server

I'm working on a site where I show a map with custom markers on positions I load from the database. Local this works perfect but live it doesn't work. For both environments I have the same API key.

When I look at the calls made when loading the map on the server I see a call to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?.

Locally I get a response with a static map. On the server the response is empty/blank. The status is '200' which suggests it was a successful call. Locally there are also a lot of calls to small tiles with more details. On the server those call are missing completely.

Has anyone experienced something like this and might have a solution? Could it have to do with the API key? Anyone an idea at all?

Thanks,
Willem

Comment: Google will usually show an alert if your API key is not valid for the domain you're using it on, so I'm hesitant to say that it's your API key. Could you post a link to your live code? You could always verify that your API key is valid by going to https://code.google.com/apis/console, click on "Credentials" under "APIs & Auth" and make sure you are using a key that works on your live domain.

Comment: I double checked my API key via code.google.com/apis/console and it doesn't seem to have any errors. Unfortunatly I can't provide an URL to the live site because it is behind a login.

Comment: You might want to check out this post: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/272652-solved-jquery-map-showing-403-forbidden-eror/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently our system administrators blocked all ports. This seems to be the issue.